# Too many results for apache solr search

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using apache solr 5.1.

There are more than 13000 documents in solr index , I am indexing pdf documents with apache tikka.

for improving search relevancy I am using edimax parser , and it works perfectly , i get expected results on top.

But instead of having only 3 results for single word query, it returns more than 400 results , with 3 expected results on top and other results are irrelevant.

Here is my field type i am using for almost all fields in schema.xml

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>

        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>

        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />

        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />

        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1"     generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"     splitOnCaseChange="1" />

  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">      
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1"     generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"     splitOnCaseChange="1" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Sample query parameters.

```
 {
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 149,
    "params": {
      "mm": "100%",
      "qs": "10",
      "ps": "10",
      "indent": "true",
      "q.op": "AND",
      "lowercaseOperators": "true",
      "q": "b4u",
      "defType": "edismax",
      "qf": "story_title^5.0  tax_payer_name^3.0  judgement_text^1.0  story_description^1.0  nature_of_the_issues  decision_summary  additional_comments  facts_of_the_case  section_number  case_law_citation",
      "pf": "story_title^5.0  tax_payer_name^3.0  judgement_text^1.0  story_description^1.0  nature_of_the_issues  decision_summary  additional_comments  facts_of_the_case  section_number  case_law_citation",
      "wt": "json",
      "stopwords": "true",
      "_": "1468224236421"
    }
  },
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please share the query or the text you are searching?

Comment: I tried to search words like 'b4u' or 'ids' and also a phrase query like "different stand in one transaction"

Comment: I have posted sample query in question

Comment: as you having WordDelimiterFilterFactory as filter , it will generate many text ...you can verify the same in analysis tool as you have generateWordParts="1"     generateNumberParts="1" and you are searching against many fields... sothe reason you will get the more count in result

Comment: Agree with you, but its returning results , which does not have query term at all and moreover these irrelevant results on top

Comment: I think this mm : "100%" is what causing the issue ...I am not very sure on this as I never used...The default value of mm is 100% (meaning that all clauses must match). Can you check with some other values as specified in the document?

Comment: yes I am expecting all words should match in query ,that's why i used mm=100% , I tried with other values as well , but no effect

Comment: You have a porter stem filter and a word delimiter filter. The stemming filter will chop off ends of terms to make more terms match the "core" of a token. Having the keyword filter _after_ the stemming filter doesn't make sense either as it will just repeat all the tokens already produced, and the word filter delimiter will make terms like "b4u" be indexed as "b" "4" "u". Use the "Analysis" page under the Solr Admin to see exactly why text matches a given query (do this for one of the irrelevant pages, and you'll quickly see why it shows up).

Comment: Thanks matslindh , I removed  word filter delimiter , but still issue persists

Comment: @Nilesh That's not the only point I raised. The Analysis page is your primary source for debugging matches. It will tell you exactly which tokens are generated - both for the query and for the indexing. The same tokens has to be generated on both sides for the query to match (the number of tokens to match depends on `q.op` or `mm`). Just removing a filter won't do much if you don't know why you're removing it. Adding `debugQuery=true` to a query will also return the contribution to the score for each token.

Comment: yes matslindh , I checked on analysis page , its generating tokens like b ,4, u at index time, but I have removed word delimiter and re indexed all documents

Comment: The configuration shown here will plainly not work technically. You cannot put character filter after token filter. I don't think the schema should even load. Based on that, I am suspecting that the schema file you think you are using maybe a completely different one (different location, etc). Have a look in the analysis screen of the Admin UI and see what the actual type definition is.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by removing HTMLStripCharFilterFactory , It was supposed to remove html chars while indexing , but it was indexing "b4u" as "b","4" and "U" which results in too many results.

I am now removing html tags by php strip_tags function while indexing.